# Mongodb query with http interface: How to use nt equal($ne)

Tags: mongodb

I am querying mongodb collection with $ne in http interface.

**Working**:
query in cli: db.collection.find('code':{'$ne':100}})
http query: http://server:28017/db/collection/?filter_code=100

**Not working** :
query in cli: db.collection.find('code':{'$ne':100}})
http query: http://server:28017/db/collection/?filter_code!=100

query with $ne is not working. Could you please let me know how to user $ne with mongodb http query.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try fixing the missing brace?

db.collection.find({'code':{'$ne':100}})

Comment: I'm really curious why you'd ever want to use the http interface (which is disabled by default, for security purposes).

Comment: We are using for some internal tool. which will help in finding out the collection data over http instead of login into mongodb console

Answer (score 0):

**its Pretty simple. You cannot use != in query string.**

You need to build around a different logic around it to execute this case. Say an additional param checktype which may contain two values in, notin or equal and not equal.

and then you decode based on passed values.

The other simple approach would be to pass the value ! as url encoding char. you can get the details in here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: I tried the same way but gave me the same output. without any data.

http://server:28017/db/collection/?filter_code%21=100

OUTPUT:

{
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [

  ],

  "total_rows" : 0 ,
  "query" : { "code!" : 100 } ,
  "millis" : 906
}